# Trace web redirection in bash script

Tags: bash, script, download, wget, web

I want to make a script to download the image at best resolution (not the preview image) from a deviantART link, as if I clicked the "Download" button.

However, it seems that deviantART redirect the browser to download the image from another source, and I can't find how to get this source via the bash script.

For example, I want to give this link as input:

> http://earthsong9405.deviantart.com/art/The-Big-Boys-357700214

And get the image located here:

> http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/077/1/c/the_big_boys_by_earthsong9405-d5wyr92.png

Via the address given by the link in the download button:

> _http://www.deviantart.com/download/357700214/the_big_boys_by_earthsong9405-d5wyr92.png?token=add3c3dbf4112b7140930c574a819878509c7ebc&ts=1403209394

Answer (score 0):

Till the code of the page will be of this type you can do it
with a little script as the one below:

```
MyUrl=$1

File_Url=$(wget -q -O - "$MyUrl")    # here you put the file html in a variable 
Line=$(echo "$File_Url" |grep -e 'meta name="og:image"')   # select only 1 line
# echo $Line
Img=$(echo $Line |sed -e 's/<meta name="og:image" content="//g' -e 's/">//g')
# echo $File_To_Download
wget -q  $Img
```

The *url* of the image you are searching for is included in a tag `meta name="og:image"`
So you can download with `wget` the page, pass through `grep` to select a **unique line**,
clean of what is not needed with `sed`.
Once you obtain in this way the url of your image (in the script in inside the variable `Img`), you can use again `wget` to download it.

This is valid till the internal code of the page will be of this type. Else you have to find another way to select the unique tag that is interesting for you.